# Can't use APT-GET after failed dependencies thing for Acestream

Tags: apt, dependencies

I have read similar issues but I can't do apt-get install -f because it wants to remove a lot of things from ubuntu and asks for a whole sentence confirmation.

I think it will break the OS if i do that. Here's my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 acestream:i386 : Depends: python2.7:i386 (>= 2.7.2) but it is not installed
                  Depends: python2.7-apsw:i386
                  Depends: python2.7-m2crypto:i386
                  Depends: python-appindicator:i386 (>= 0.4.1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: liba52-0.7.4:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libass4:i386 (>= 0.9.7) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libavcodec53:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed or
                           libavcodec-extra-53:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libavformat53:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed or
                           libavformat-extra-53:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libavutil51:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed or
                           libavutil-extra-51:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libcddb2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libcdio10:i386 but it is not installable or
                           libcdio13:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libdc1394-22:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libdca0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libdirac-encoder0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libdvbpsi7:i386 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libdvdnav4:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libdvdread4:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libebml3:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libfaad2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libfribidi0:i386 (>= 0.19.2) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libqt4-webkit:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libkate1:i386 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not installed
                  Depends: liblircclient0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: liblua5.1-0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libmatroska5:i386 but it is not installed or
                           libmatroska4:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libmodplug1:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libmpcdec6:i386 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libmpeg2-4:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libmtp9:i386 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libpostproc52:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed or
                           libpostproc-extra-52:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.7) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libsmbclient:i386 (>= 3.0.24) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libswscale2:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed or
                           libswscale-extra-2:i386 (>= 4:0.7-1) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libtar0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libtwolame0:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libupnp6:i386 but it is not installable or
                           libupnp4:i386 but it is not installed or
                           libupnp3:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libva-x11-1:i386 (> 1.0.12~) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libva1:i386 (> 1.0.12~) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libvcdinfo0:i386 (> 0.7.23) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libx264-116:i386 but it is not installable or
                           libx264-120:i386 but it is not installed or
                           libx264-123:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: ttf-freefont:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Help Please!!! Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command first and check whether you are able to install as you wanted.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If not able to do so try purging and reinstall it.

```
apt-get purge
```

Comment: All of these except the update do not finish and result in the same output as above. For some reason it's stuck on that install and doesn't want to finish but -f mode doesn't just say it will install dependencies but also that it will remove a lot of things among which ubuntu-* stuff.